# XSLT Browser Transform; What am I missing?

Tags: xslt

Let me immediately say that I'm very new to this web-based programming.  With that out of the way, here's my situation:

I've got an application where I need to generate XML files from a piece of hardware with only the most rudimentary web server application running on it.  There isn't a lot of "real estate" or extra horsepower to work with in the hardware, so I'm looking to generate an XML file with commands, parameters, and other information related to the configuration of the hardware, and then send it along to a web browser which has connected to the web server.  I am hoping to be able to link the XML document to the transform which would be hosted on the hardware.  I believe this can be done with the stylesheet href.

I'm having a problem when I use the following line at the top of the XML file:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text\xsl" href="C:\6850XML\XSL6850.xslt"?>
```

Now obviously, this is for debugging on the workstation before deployment to the hardware.  When I open the XML files in IE, I get the XML file literally.  In Firefox, I get a parsed version of the XML.  When I run the XSLT debugger from within VS2K10, I get the webpage that I wanted.  This is likely because you manually specify which XML file you want to use for the transform in the development environment.  What am I doing wrong with the stylesheet href?  Should the type be something else?

Sorry for what I'm sure will be a basic question, but I'm scratching my already hairless head here.

Comment: http://davidjarvis.ca/playlists/  View the source for the frame. It is an XML/XSL-based web page that renders HTML using the browser's XSLT engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `type="text/xsl"` and the href attribute should be a URL, not a Windows file path so try `href="file:///C:/6850XML/XSL6850.xslt"`. However linking from a resource on the web to a stylesheet on the local file system is probably not going to work in nowadays browsers due to security restrictions.

Comment: I probably just worded that explanation poorly.  The ultimate plan is to establish a connection to a webserver running in a piece of hardware within a network(usually sitting in a lab down the hall from a user) and then get the stylesheet from that same piece of hardware.

Comment: Rich, if you load both the XML and the stylesheet from the same origin then browsers should apply the stylesheet (once you make the corrections already suggested (i.e. using `text/xsl` instead of `text\xsl` and using proper URL syntax)). Otherwise checks the error console of the browser, Mozilla/Firefox at least log any security related problems there.

Comment: A relative path would probably be the best plan: that can work both locally *and* on whatever servers you might use.

Answer (score 1):

The net runs on *nix/BSD so forward slashes are always in order. Fix your 'text/xsl'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the browser is not reaching the stylesheet. It could be because your wrong `type="text\xsl"`pseudo attribute and the URI protocol (not handled by browser, security restrictions).

**Solution:** use a relative URI like

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSL6850.xslt"?>
```

Tested on my desktop every time